# Search icon of search field disappears in sencha

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

When navigating to new view search icon of search field disappears in sencha touch , Also the search field shrinks little since I'm adding an extra button. How can I prevent shrinking of search field or how can I maintain the search field icon?

```
    Ext.define('Proj.view.Home', {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
    xtype: 'homeTabItem',
    id: 'home',

this.add(
            {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                id: 'SeachToolbar',
                docked: 'top',
               items: [
                   {
                       xtype: 'searchfield',
                       align: 'left',
                       width:200,
                       placeHolder: 'Search'

                   },

                   {
                       id : 'searchButton_h',
                       xtype : 'button',
                       iconCls : 'search',
                       iconMask : true,
                       align : 'left',
                       scope:this,
                       handler:this.onSearchKeyUp
                   },

                   {

                       id : 'homeSelect',
                       xtype: 'selectfield',
                       hidden:true; 
                       iconMask : true,
                       align : 'right',
                       width : '20%',
                   }
    ]});
```

On a pushed view I'm making 'homeSelect' visible and my serchfield's magnifier icon disappears..

Comment: Are you sure the code you pasted is working ? You're calling the add function within a config object...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a

```
var PnlQuejaReclamo = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                    id: 'PnlQuejaReclamo',
                    title: 'Quejas Reclamos',
                    layout: 'border',
                    tbar: [{
                            width: 200,
                            id:'Reclamo',
                            emptyText: 'Buscar...',
                            xtype: 'searchfield',
                            store: StoreQuejaReclamo,
                            params: {start: 0, limit: 100}
                        }, '->', {
                            itemId: 'create',
                            text: 'Agregar',
                            iconCls: 'agregar',
                            hrefTarget: 'quejareclamo/create',
                            handler: function(btn) {
                                btn.TipoIndicador = 3;
                                btn.Titulo = ' Queja Reclamo';
                                new SistIntegral.FrmQR.QuejaReclamo().Window(btn);
                            }
                        }, '-', {
                            itemId: 'edit',
                            text: 'Editar',
                            iconCls: 'editar',
                            hrefTarget: 'quejareclamo/edit/',
                            handler: function(btn) {
                                btn.TipoIndicador = 3;
                                btn.Titulo = ' Queja Reclamo';
                                new SistIntegral.FrmQR.QuejaReclamo().Window(btn);
                            }
                        }, '-', {
                            itemId: 'eliminar',
                            text: 'Eliminar',
                            iconCls: 'eliminar',
                            handler: function() {
                            },
                            disabled: true
                        }
                    ],
                    items: [gridQuejaReclamo, PnlDetalles],
                    closable: false
                });
```